# Spring MVC, validate if request has duplicate params

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, kotlin, interceptor

We have multipart post request mapped to below method.

```
fun post(@RequestParam(value = "photo", required = true) photo: Array<MultipartFile>,
         @Valid person: Person)

class Person {
  int id,
  String name
}
```

In the below example has more than one `name` param in the request

```
localhost:8080/api
post body:
id:101
name: Jhon
name: Jhonny
```

Is there a way to reject the request if it contains repeated params?

Comment: You can replace `String name` by `List<String> name` and check yourself the length of the list in your method.

Comment: We can can change the structure of model for validation. where ever person model is being used it creates problem.

Comment: You could create a DTO to handle this and then convert it into a `Person` before calling your service.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `HttpServletRequest` to the handler method argument list, validate it, and return a `ReponseEntity.badRequest().build()` if there are multiple occurrences of the same parameters.

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity handlerMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {

    if (request.getParameterValues("name").length > 1) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

If you want to do it across the whole application you can define a filter:

```
@Component
class DuplicateRequestParameterFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    Enumeration<String> parameters = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (parameters.hasMoreElements()) {
        if (request.getParameterValues(parameters.nextElement()).length > 1) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: it applies across application not only to Person Model, all models in application, need generic way of handling.

Comment: Thank you, and we can not hard code 'name' here, as there can be many properties and different model classes used for different controllers

Comment: Updated. Should now work independently of the parameter name.

Comment: Using this solution giving me owasp XSS attack. any pointers?

Comment: XSS can be caused by unsanitized responses, maybe that causes the problem. I'm not sure it's related to the filter.

Comment: and there is a deadlock situation:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402857/how-to-encode-response-to-json-in-filter-without-failing-xss

Answer (score 0):

no,there would be a array named 'name' or a string which contain two name,it is looked like this
`{id:101,name:'Jhon,Jhonny'}` or `{id:101,name:['Jhon','Jhonny']}`
which is determined by how to receive it 
if name is a string ,the result would be 'Jhon,Jhonny'.
if name is a string array ,the result would by ['Jhon','Jhonny'].