# How to encode response to JSON in filter without failing XSS

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, security, owasp, spotbugs

BELOW IS THE static code analysis report from SpotBugs

XSS_SERVLET: Potential XSS in Servlet
A potential XSS was found. It could be used to execute unwanted JavaScript in a client's browser. (See references)

Vulnerable Code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
String input1 = req.getParameter("input1");
[...]
resp.getWriter().write(input1);
}
```

Solution:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)     throws ServletException, IOException {
    String input1 = req.getParameter("input1");
    [...]
    resp.getWriter().write(Encode.forHtml(input1))
```

Encode.forJava for JavaScript is writing special chars and JSON string is compromised.

How to use Encoder to send JSON string. without failing security CHECK

Comment: Can I use HandlerInterceptor instead of Filter?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could have a look at OWASP JSON sanitizer https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_JSON_Sanitizer#tab=Main ?